# Does Picard ever agree with Worf that the best course of action is to fire torpedos?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, worf, jean-luc-picard

Most of the time when there is a threat or encounter with something foreign, Worf, as chief of security from season 2 of TNG onwards, recommends to load and arm torpedoes and phasers, normally followed by recommending firing them.  Picard normally rejects this recommendation.  Is there ever any time when Picard agrees that the best course of action is to fire torpedoes and phasers?  (Note - I am not asking about a situation where the Enterprise/Federation is already at war, but more like a first-contact situation.)

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?  I'm not asking for opinion, only actual answers.

Comment: I'm with N. Soong on this. The downvotes are unnecessary. I actually think it's an interesting question, though I suspect the answer is a resounding no.

Comment: Come on people. Only seven seasons to watch to come up with a definitive answer. Get cracking.

Comment: Agreed - I think it is totally valid to ask if the chief of security ever had a real say in first engagement.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - nope. The answer is "Negative"

Comment: @DVK: That was nowhere near enough time to watch all seven seasons. I call shenanigans.

Comment: Acting-Captain Riker took Worf's advice in "Time's Arrow Part II". Worf was all "let's blow it up, dude" and Riker was all "yeah, go on then"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do the movies count? If so, I think *First Contact* would be a perfect example for this. Okay, it's against the Borg and Worf isn't technically still part of the crew, yet Picard's first reaction is to assuming command over the remainders of the fleet and immediately transmitting coordinates to fire at - not just for the Enterprise, but for all remaining ships. While Worf isn't on the Enterprise at that moment, he clearly agrees and doesn't want to abandon the Defiant to continue fighting. Overall, the whole movie depicts a quite aggressive Picard and he obviously doesn't stop trying to "murder" the Borg later on during the Holodeck scenes.

Comment: That wasn't a first contact situation, and for that matter the Federation was already at war with the Borg. In the middle of a battle, actually. That's very different from the question asked above. In fact, I don't think your answer actually relates to the question at all, the more I read it.

Comment: Sorry Mario, but @James is right - I was asking about a first-contact situation when Worf specifically posed the recommendation and Picard rejected him.  I expect, however, this is as close as we're going to get.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's going to be even more interesting. :) You should add that to your question (more prominent than "encounter with something foreign", since "when there is a threat" is kinda vague).

Comment: I get the feeling this is the closest we're going to get - sorry Mr Worf: you're just too jumpy

Comment: Even better example from that movie: after the enterprise (with Worf onboard) follows the Borg sphere back in time, Picard says "Mr Worf, Quantum Torpedoes." "Ready, sir." "Fire."

Answer (score 11):

I've noticed this too. I've been watching TNG from day one and have taped every episode. Not once to my memory has Worf's recommendation to fire first EVER been taken. There has to be a T.V. Trope in there somewhere. It almost seems that Worf is being used as a foil to illustrate that 'aggression' is almost never warranted and is just a savage reaction. So he's 'put in his place' and proved wrong time after time.

Comment: You could even go a bit further: the head of security almost always tries to get things insecure for his own crew as well? Hm... :)

Comment: Except more than once, Worf's suggestion to shoot first would've prevented a lot of headache for the crew later.  But then, we wouldn't have an episode if Worf blew up the plot device.

Comment: Heh. "Fire the MacGuffins!"

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174789/6133 According to this answer there are several times his recommendations have been taken,