# Was there ever a situation where a proposal from Worf was accepted?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I recently stumbled upon this video which is a 15 minute compilation of Star Trek: The Next Generation scenes where Worf makes proposals which immediately get dismissed:

That made me wonder if this is actually an accurate representation of how the Enterprise-D crew treated Worf. Are there any examples of episodes in ST:TNG where Worf proposed a course of action and the other characters agreed to it without further discussion?

Comment: And before someone votes: no, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/does-picard-ever-agree-with-worf-that-the-best-course-of-action-is-to-fire-torpe). While it uses the same video, it does not ask about how Worf is treated. It asks about whether or not Picard ever fired first in a conflict.

Comment: What about when Worf proposed to Deanna?

Comment: @Edlothiad I was going to say the same of his proposal to Jadzia Dax...

Comment: @Vanguard3000 That was on DS9, though.

Comment: Now I want to know how many times he was denied, but it turns out the thing he said to do was correct.

Comment: Worf has made many reliable suggestions during the Enterprise's confrontations with Klingon vessels and other attacking vessels.

Comment: You could probably come up with similar clips featuring just about every character in Star Trek that we see on screen to any significant degree. Everyone occasionally makes suggestions which are denied; in at least a hundred hours of total screen time per series, surely you can find many examples if you go looking for them. Not even the captain's suggestions are always approved of, though the captain of the ship usually get their way in the end anyway.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**There are a number of occasions where Worf's suggestions were immediately actioned by the crew of the Enterprise.**

In [**TNG: Time's Arrow**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_(episode)) he proposed that they fire torpedoes on Captain Picard's location. With only a slight hesitation (presumably because killing his captain isn't going to look good on his resumé), Riker agrees.

> **WORF:** *The Captain would not. I recommend we target photon torpedoes on the alien habitat and destroy it. Immediately.*
>
> **TROI:** *He's right, Will.*
>
> **RIKER:** *Power up the photons, Mister Worf. Alert me when they're ready.*

In [**TNG: Skin of Evil**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)) Worf tells the captain that he thinks he should stay on the ship. Picard readily accepts.

> **WORF:** *I will remain on the ship. The object here is not to engage the creature in battle. The goal is the safe return of Counsellor Troi
> and Lieutenant Prieto. I can best accomplish this at the Tactical
> Station.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Very good. Number One?*

In [**TNG: The Outrageous Okona**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Outrageous_Okona_(episode)) he suggests that the roguish Okana should only be given access to the public areas of the ship.

> **WORF:** *Sir, recommend limited access to our ship.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Agreed.*

In [**TNG: Cost of Living**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cost_of_Living_(episode)) Worf suggests that they evacuate some areas of the ship. Picard readily agreed.

> **WORF:** *We must evacuate decks twenty through twenty four, Captain.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Make it so. Shut down life support to those decks.*

In [**TNG: Clues**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Clues_(episode)) Worf points out that they're within the blast radius of their own torpedoes.

> **WORF:** *I do not recommend weapons at this range, Captain.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Can we go to warp?*

In [**TNG: The Next Phase**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Next_Phase_(episode)) Worf is adamant that they can't give the Romulans a computer core. Riker comes up with an alternate solution to appease him.

> **WORF:** *Commander, the* (looks round) *the Romulans want a computer. We cannot give them access to Federation technology. That is
> an unacceptable security risk.*
>
> **RIKER:** *What about a computer core from thirty or forty years ago? One the Romulans are already familiar with.*
>
> **WORF:** *That would be satisfactory.*

In [**TNG: Galaxy's Child**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy%27s_Child_(episode)) Picard is practically his best buddy, accepting not one but two(!) proposals from Worf, that they move back and that they fire phasers.

> **WORF:** *Sir, the shuttlecraft shields did not provide sufficient protection for its computer. Our computer may also be vulnerable. I
> recommend withdrawal to a safe distance.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Ensign Anaya, full about. Half impulse.*
>
> ...
>
> **WORF:** *Sir, recommend full phasers*.
>
> **PICARD:** *Proceed.*

In [**TNG: Lower Decks**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lower_Decks_(episode)), Worf proposes that they could use a probe to augment their sensors. Riker points out the obvious legal implications (as he's supposed to) but Picard is happy to agree with Worf.

> **WORF:** *Sir, I recommend we launch a probe to increase the range of our sensor sweeps.*
>
> **RIKER:** *Launching a probe into Cardassian space would be a treaty violation.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Mister Worf, prepare a probe and launch when ready.*

In [**TNG: Chain of Command**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_Command,_Part_I_(episode)), Worf offers his advice on how to get through an obstruction.

> **WORF:** *A phaser set to level sixteen should suffice.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Make it so.*

Worf is on fire in [**TNG: Eye of the Beholder**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_(episode)) with two suggestions accepted by Troi; that they rummage a dead crewman's computer files and that they start early the next day.

> **WORF:** *We should check his personal logs.*
>
> **TROI:** *This is his last entry. He made it before going on duty this morning.*
>
> ...
>
> **WORF:** *We should get an early start tomorrow.*
>
> **TROI:** *I think we should. I'll see you in the morning.*

And in the TNG film [**Star Trek: Insurrection**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection) Worf is very clear in his proposal that they have to prioritise fixing their dampening fields in order to prevent the crew from being flung around.

> **WORF:** *We must stabilise the dampening fields.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Reroute emergency power to inertial dampers.*

Comment: Your google-fu out ranks my google-fu

Comment: @CBredlow - It's definitely not worth the effort. Sisko and Kira were more than happy to accept his proposals, of which there were several dozen

Comment: [Skin of Evil](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)) is an early *TNG* example, when Worf suggests that he can serve the rescue mission better at his tactical station than by joining the away team as initially ordered.

Comment: @Gaultheria - A good find. I've added it in.

Comment: Technically, Worf suggested self destructing the ship and evacuating in *First Contact*: https://youtu.be/Q1VKPUey94M. Picard took convincing, but it was the course of action they took (with Picarding tacking on his staying behind).

Comment: Another addition to an excellent list: [The Emissary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emissary_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)): _However, Worf comes up with another option. [..] Worf and K'Ehleyr, clad in full traditional Klingon command uniforms, appear as captain and first officer of the Enterprise, informing Captain K'Temoc of the T'Ong that the war is over and ordering them to surrender._ We see Worf start making a suggestion, his explanation (and Picard's agreement) happen off-screen, but afterwards we see Worf executing his plan.

Comment: @Flater - We don't know how much convincing it took for Picard, nor whether the plan was actioned unchanged

Comment: @jpmc26 - I've tried to avoid instances where *too much* discussion was needed. Per the original question "*where Worf proposed a course of action **and the other characters agreed to it without further discussion?*"**

Comment: In [The Next Phase](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Next_Phase_(episode)), he informs Riker that the Romulans' request for a modern computer core is an unacceptable security risk, and Riker agrees and has an older model sent over instead.

Comment: @Shadur - A good find. I've added it in.

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm pretty sure Valorum just has the episodes memorized - the scripts are only looked up because it's faster to copy and paste.

Comment: @corsiKa - It certainly doesn't hurt to have seen each episode a few times

Answer (score 9):

Yes, his recommendation was accepted in the episode, *[The Emissary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emissary_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))*.

A Klingon emissary (and Worf's mate), K'Ehleyr, informs the command staff that Starfleet has detected a Klingon battlecruiser called the T'Ong, which was launched from the Klingon homeworld over 75 years ago, when the Klingons and the Federation were still at war. The crew has been in suspended animation and are about to awaken, at which point it is feared they will immediately attack the nearest Federation outpost, several of which are nearby and would not be able to adequately defend themselves.

K'Ehleyr urges Picard to let the Klingons die with honor, in battle. However, Worf comes up with another option. While Picard and first officer Commander Riker position themselves out of sight, Worf and K'Ehleyr, clad in full traditional Klingon command uniforms, appear as captain and first officer of the Enterprise, informing Captain K'Temoc of the T'Ong that the war is over and ordering them to surrender. K'Temoc initially refuses, believing it to be a Federation trick, but when Worf, in typical Klingon manner, shows his resolve and threatens to destroy the T'Ong, K'Temoc grudgingly agrees.